# Chrome Zoom doesn't change getBoundingClientRect values

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, cross-browser, zooming

If I use

```
document.getElementbyId("myElement").getBoundingClientRect.x;
```

in firefox, it will account for zoom level.
So an element that is at 590px x-axis at 100% zoom, will be at 590*2px x-axis at 200% zoom.

In chrome, if an element is at 590px x-axis and I zoom to 200%, the x will still be at 590px even though it should be at 1180px x-axis.

Do all browsers handle this differently? Any ideas on how I can responsively detect this behaviour and recalculate x-position?
I am making a game in javascript and the canvas is positioned in the middle of the screen (absolute) and if people zoom in or out I cannot read mouse coordinates correctly.
Still though, I want to allow people to zoom so they can adjust my "fixed" canvas size to the display they are on. 
*(also it is just an annoying bug...)*

Comment: What "zoom" are you talking about? The browser one when you hit ctrl +? If that's so, then your FF is broken (but note I can't reproduce on mine). getBoundingClientRect's unit is css `px`. When you use the browser zoom, this unit gets scaled, so whatever the zoom level a `50px` line always measures `50px`, even though it may now require using twice the number of your monitor's diodes to render it. Or maybe you just didn't realize your browser scrolled the page when you zoomed in?

Comment: you were right! I was setting zoom on css so it screwed with chrome and thats why it didnt work, on firefox i was using transform so it worked :O